# BCS energy gap in superconductivity: Microwave apsorption as proof

Tags: superconductivity, fermi-energy

A quick question. The BCS theory predicts the existence of the energy gap below the Fermi level. The experimental proof is the absorption of the EM radiation in the microwave spectrum. Why/How? Could anyone explain how the absorption is the proof of it?
Much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers depends on how much you know about band theory in solids. If you are comfortable with this concept the reasoning is pretty simple.

In a solid, the absorption of a photon excites an electron across an interband transition. When a metal goes into the superconducting state, the appearance of an energy gap at the Fermi level, by definition, means that now you have a band below $E_F$ and another above.

The size of the gap in all conventional superconductors fall in the 500 GHz range or below. Therefore, that is the band splitting. Sending a photon of that energy will produce an electronic transition across the band gap (the superconducting gap), hence an absorption peak in the optical spectrum.

In a regular metal, you have no peak as there is no band splitting. The existence of a peak in the microwave in the superconducting state shows that now you have opened a gap at $E_F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!